# How to make a Help page, Inventory display, and Take items in a JS game

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea that displays all of the actions of the player, and have a separate command box for moving and for entering commands 'h' for help 'i' for items, and 't' for take an item. The thing is I'm stuck as to how to accomplish this. It would be great for some help mainly on the help and inventory part. Here is what I got so far:

```
//Global Variables
var currentLocale = 0;
var direction = false;
var check = false;
function updateDisplay() {
    msg = "";
    if (direction!=true){
        if (check!=true){

            switch (currentLocale) {

                case 0:  msg = "Your home...Earth.";
                         break;
                case 1:  msg = "On Mercury.";
                         break;
                case 2:  msg = "On Mars.";
                         break;
                case 3:  msg = "On Saturn.";
                         break;
                case 4:  msg = "On Venus.";
                         break;
                case 5:  msg = "On Neptune.";
                         break;
                case 6:  msg = "On Jupiter.";
                         break;
                case 7:  msg = "On Uranus.";
                         break;    
                default: msg = "You broke me.";

            }


        }else{
            msg="Please enter a valid command ( listed below).";
            check=false;
        }
    }else{
        msg="You can not go this way."
        direction=false;
    }

    taPtr = document.getElementById("taDisplay");
    history = taPtr.value;
    taPtr.value =  msg +"\n"+ history; 

}
//             N   S   E   W 
var nav = [
    [ 1, -1, -1, -1 ], // Earth    
    [ 2, 0,-1, -1 ],    //Mercury
    [ -1, 1, 3, 4],    //Mars                     
    [ -1, -1, -1, 2], // Saturn   
    [ 5, 6, 2, -1],    //Venus
    [ -1, 4, -1, -1],  //Neptune
    [ 4, 7, -1, -1],   //Jupiter
    [ 6, -1, -1, -1],  //Uranus
];

function  go(dir){               
    var  dirNum=-1;        //Global Variable 
    if (dir == 'N'){
        dirNum=0;
    }else if (dir =='S'){
        dirNum=1;
    }else if (dir == 'E'){
        dirNum=2;
    }else if (dir == 'W'){
        dirNum=3;
    };
    changeLocale(dirNum);
}


function changeLocale(dirNum){

    var temp= nav[currentLocale][dirNum];

    if (dirNum != -1){
        if(temp >= 0 ) {    
            currentLocale= temp;  

        }else {
            direction=true;
        }

    }else {
        check= true;  
    }                                            
    updateDisplay();  

} 

function commandInput(){

    var dirNum=-1;                  
    var comm=document.getElementById("commandBox").value;
    var command= comm.toUpperCase();

    switch(command){
        case 'N': dirNum=0;
                  break;
        case 'S': dirNum=1;
                  break;
        case 'E': dirNum=2;
                  break;
        case 'W': dirNum=3;
                  break;
        default : msg= ('You broke me.');
                  break;
    }
    changeLocale(dirNum);



}
```

Thanks in advance.